# UIImage as Parameter: Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios4, uiimage, xcode4.2

The code below is the image picker callback that runs after the user takes a photo with the camera / or picks a photo from the library.

Can someone explain to me why the first version works and second version throws an error?

The first version passes a UIImage from a synthesised UIImageView to method scaleAndRotateImage.

The second version declares a local UIImageView and passes the image to method scaleAndRotateImage.

This is the first version that works::

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

VC_Create_Preview *vc_create_preview =  [[VC_Create_Preview alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC_Create_Preview" bundle:nil];

//UIImageView *temp = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
//temp.image = [self scaleAndRotateImage:temp.image];
//vc_create_preview.origImage = temp;

srcImageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
srcImageView.image = [self scaleAndRotateImage:srcImageView.image];
vc_create_preview.origImage = srcImageView;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc_create_preview animated:YES];

}
```

But the 2nd version below does not, and throws an error when calling method scaleAndRotateImage (note in debug i cannot even step "into" scaleAndRotateImage)

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

VC_Create_Preview *vc_create_preview =  [[VC_Create_Preview alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC_Create_Preview" bundle:nil];

UIImageView *temp = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
temp.image = [self scaleAndRotateImage:temp.image];
vc_create_preview.origImage = temp;

//srcImageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
//srcImageView.image = [self scaleAndRotateImage:srcImageView.image];
//vc_create_preview.origImage = srcImageView;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc_create_preview animated:YES];

}
```

The error thrown by the 2nd version is

```
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""VC_Create_Capture.m":97" resolved
2012-01-04 20:33:52.674 MultiInterfaceTest[430:f803] -[UIImage image]: unrecognized     selector sent to instance 0x68aac00
2012-01-04 20:33:52.717 MultiInterfaceTest[430:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught    exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage image]: unrecognized selector     sent to instance 0x68aac00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13c2052 0x1553d0a 0x13c3ced 0x1328f00 0x1328ce2 0x35df 0x211c52 0xbfaa305 0xbfbe5fd     0xc022fef 0x2dde39 0x2dd143 0x2de3cf 0x2e0a31 0x2e098c 0x2d93e7 0x41812 0x41ba2 0x28384 0x1baa9 0x12acfa9 0x13961c5 0x12fb022 0x12f990a 0x12f8db4 0x12f8ccb 0x12ab879 0x12ab93e 0x19a9b 0x23b8 0x2315)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

Answer (score 0):

"-[UIImage image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68aac00"

It seems that the [UIImageView image] accessor method gets called on an UIImage object. Most likely it's a memory management error: the UIImageView gets deallocated, and its memory is filled with the UIImage instance, erronously. (Unrelated: you're also leaking memory in the first approach. -pushViewController:animated: retains the view controller, so you must -release it.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean that "temp" (the UIImageView) gets deallocated when I use the accessor "temp.image"? That sounds strange, not used to that happening in other languages...

Also i'm running in ARC (Auto reference counting) mode so I cannot do a [vc_create_preview release] after pushing it onto the navigation controller. I find this convenient but not sure if ARC is the recommended way to go. Cheers

Comment: No, that's not the reason. I don't know why it is getting deallocated. Maybe the containing dictionary is released. I would need some more code in order to be able to determine the precise reason. And no, accessors don't deallocate objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is because some where you have  called image API on UIImage Class. image is a method of UIImageView class not UIImage. thats why Xcode is throwing this error.

To resolve it make sure that you are  calling
So please sure that you are calling the image API on UIImage View class not UIImage. Check all the variables you have declare in your .h file and make sure you have used UIImageView class instead of UIImage.

Unrecongnized selector means that your class does not support the any image API that you have called inside your code.

Comment: Hi Sandeep. As the code is shown above, I have locally declared *temp as a UIImageView, and the error is occurring on the line:

temp.image = [self scaleAndRotateImage:temp.image];

So i don't think its because i'm calling the "image" selector on a "UIImage" class?

Comment: Hi Kevin, this is because in your code on line:- UIImageView *temp = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; you have used temp variable as UIImageView class while the info [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] always returns the UIImage object. and you are calling the image on UIImage object on that line. just modify your line like to:-UIImage *temp = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];and this will correct your problem and will not crash.

Comment: and then before calling  second line:- temp.image = [self scaleAndRotateImage:temp.image]; you need to convert the image object you are getting on previous line to UIImageView class. Otherwise  your code crash again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys i found the answer.
The following is wrong because the [info objectForKey....] returns a UIImage, not a UIImageView.
Hence its probably that temp wasn't probably created hence an error from the 2nd line of the code.

```
UIImageView *temp = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
temp.image = [self scaleAndRotateImage:temp.image];
vc_create_preview.origImage = temp;
```

Thanks everyone!